# Scala Test: Auto-skip tests that exceed timeout

Tags: scala, scalatest

As I have a collection of scala tests that connect with remote services (some of which may not be available at the time of test execution), I would like to have a way of indicating Scala tests that should be ignored, if the time-out exceeds a desired threshold.

Indeed, I could enclose the body of a test in a future and have it auto-pass, if the time-out is exceeded but having slow tests silently pass strikes me as risky. It would be better if it were explicitly skipped during the test run.  So, what I would really like is something like the following:

```
 ignorePast(10 seconds) should "execute a service that is sometimes unavailable" in {
      invokeServiceThatIsSometimesUnavailable()
      ....
 }
```

Looking at the ScalaTest documentation, I don't see this feature supported directly but suspect that there might be away to add this capability?  Indeed, I could just add a "tag" to "slow" tests and tell the runner not to execute them, but I would rather the tests be automatically skipped when the timeout is exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's not something you're test framework should be responsible for.
Wrap your invokeServiceThatIsSometimesUnavailable() in an exception handling block and you'll be fine.

```
try {
  invokeServiceThatIsSometimesUnavailable()
} catch {
  case e : YourServiceTimeoutException => reportTheIgnoredTest()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Maciej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27038/maciej-bi%C5%82as) that exceptions are probably the best way to go, since the timeout happens within your test itself.

There's also `assume` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096275/does-scalatest-have-any-support-for-assumptions)), which allows to cancel a test if some pre-requisite fails. You could use it also within a single test, I think.